# WAMPSERVER can not access from url localhost but 127.0.0.1 is ok ( on win8 )

Tags: wampserver

I just switch to win 8 from win 7. On win7 everything is OK with wampserver, but

When i try to access my wampserver via url localhost on win8, i got this error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

but via url 127.0.0.1 is OK.

I try fix that error by change in phpmyadmin.conf into

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.9/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow        
    Allow from all  
</Directory>
```

Could anyone help me fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've the same issue with win7

Answer (score 22):

Modify the apache HTTPD.CONF file. Change "Listen 80" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,93143

Comment: I was having the same problem on Win8, but this solved it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: great. such a tiny solution to 3hours of my misery

Comment: That worked for me as well. Now if I only I knew *why* it works... if there are any negative implications to doing this... and what caused it to suddenly stop working.

Comment: If you 'ping localhost' you will likely get the reply from '::1' which is an IPv6 format, you probably have both listed in your hosts file.  Changing httpd.conf as per this answer means Apache only listens for IPv4 so it will correctly map to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Change httpd.conf also and put Allow from all as given below.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Anti-virus like AVIRA or AVG it certenly blocked changes to localhost by adding the "::1" entry in the HOSTS file in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS
All you have to do is to remove this line (::1) or just comment it by adding "#" sign in front of it in the hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

You must install Visual Studio C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package x86 or x64

This is a must when you install [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) on a Windows 8 Machine.

Thing is, some software are built on MS Visual Studio, thus require VS C++ reditributable Packages to run.

VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe 32 bits : microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328

VC10 SP1 vcredist_x64.exe 64 bits : microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523

If above downloads don't work, try:

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

This for the applications built on latest Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

This is my .conf file...

Comment: is it OK on Win8?
My original conf is same with your conf, but it not working on Win8, just 127.0.0.1 working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried all of the above with no results.
Then, I re-install the WampServer (deleting the wamp folder manually), and this worked, but finally I caught what was wrong in my case...

I made a change on the http.conf file, I un-commented this>

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And then I opened the un-commented file to add my virtual host, but forgot to add one for the local host...
So, just by adding this in the httpd-vhosts.conf file>

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

All went back to normal...

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem by disabling the firewall for port 80.

1. Go to Search on right side of windows.
2. search "firewall".
3. open the "firewall with advanced".
4. go to inbound rules.
5. click on "new rule".
6. select the "Port" option.
7. click "next"
8. select "TCP" option.
9. select "Specific local ports:".
10. type "80" in next text box
11. click next.
12. select the "Allow the connection".
13. click "next".
14. click "next".
15. give the name "Port 80 Allow Rule".
16. click "next".

**Note: this is not a secure way. delete this newly created rule when you complete your work.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is an answer that worked for me:
in httpd.conf file:
I changed this:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This may not be a good solution, but to simply run standalone projects on localhost without sql or php is fine.